# "var" variable is used before it is assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

It seems like I need to assign some values into variable var() and I don't know how. Can someone help me fix this please.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim var() As String
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\carment\Desktop\Test.txt")
        i = 1
        For Each line As String In lines
            var(i) = line
            Console.WriteLine(var(i))
            i = i + 1
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Once you know how many elements you have in the lines array, you should use `Redim var(lines.GetUpperBound)`. Your initial declaration doesn't create any elements, so you need to `ReDim` it to the size you need. Have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the array as well:

```
var = New String(lines.Length-1) {}
```